# Calculate Total in JavaScript per input in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so I have a table that is dynamically built for my bills. I am wanting to add each amount up together and place them in a grand total.

I have the following code for calculating the totals:

```
$('.amount').blur(function () {
   var total = 0;

   $('.amount').each(function () {
       total += $(this).val();
   });

   $('.total_bills').html(total);
});
```

But it doesn't appear to be doing anything at all. It doesn't even seem to be getting called. My table structure is below:

```
 <table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Bill Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Bill Amount</th>
            <th class="text-center">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="bill_name[]" class="form-control"></td><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="bill_amount[]" class="form-control amount"></td><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="bill_status[]" class="form-control"></td></tr><tr><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="bill_name[]" class="form-control"></td><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="bill_amount[]" class="form-control amount"></td><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="bill_status[]" class="form-control"></td></tr><tr><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="bill_name[]" class="form-control"></td><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="bill_amount[]" class="form-control amount"></td><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="bill_status[]" class="form-control"></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

I have also created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ux0rsk2q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that `.amount` is created dynamically so you need to delegate the blur event to it: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ux0rsk2q/2/)**

```
function add(user) {
    $("#" + user + "Table tbody").append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td class='text-center'><input type='text' name='bill_name[]' class='form-control'></td>" +
        "<td class='text-center'><input type='text' name='bill_amount[]' class='form-control amount'></td>" +
        "<td class='text-center'><input type='text' name='bill_status[]' class='form-control'></td>" +
        "</tr>");
}

$(".addBill").click(function () {
    var user = $(this).data('user');
    add(user);
});

$(document).on('blur','.amount',function () {
    var total = 0;

    $('.amount').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $('.total_bills').html(total);
});
```

also for adding the actual amount you need to use `parseInt()` to make sure the numbers are added not the strings appended.

**UPDATE:**

this would be the best way to differ the tables and their fields:

```
$(document).on('blur','.amount',function () {
    var total = 0;

    $(this).closest('tr').find('.amount').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $(this).closest('tr').find('.total_bills').html(total);
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ux0rsk2q/9/)**

```
function add(user) {
    $("#" + user + "Table tbody").append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td class='text-center'><input type='text' name='bill_name[]' class='form-control'></td>" +
        "<td class='text-center'><input type='text' name='bill_amount[]' class='form-control amount'></td>" +
        "<td class='text-center'><input type='text' name='bill_status[]' class='form-control'></td>" +
        "</tr>");
}

$(".addBill").click(function () {
    var user = $(this).data('user');
    add(user);
});

$(document).on('blur','.amount',function () {
    var total = 0;

    $(this).closest('tbody').find('.amount').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $(this).closest('table').next().find('.total_bills').html(total);
});
```

Comment: Okay, this solved my problem. But what if I had multiple tables on the same page? How could I distinguish between what table the field was blurred in?

Comment: as you differed them before for example `$(document).on('blur','#table1 .amount',function () {})`

Comment: Well actually, now that I played around a little more. It doesn't add all the values anymore. Just takes the newest one and puts it in .total_bills

Comment: wait a bit, I'll make a fiddle for you

Answer (score 0):

Your `ammount` jQuery is called only once, after the page loads. At this time, there are no `ammount` elements. When you add a new row, it won't be called automatically, and hence your blur function is not added. You have to call it yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/darekkay/ux0rsk2q/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
 $('.amount').live('change', function() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('bill_amount[]');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total_bills').value = tot;
});
```

Comment: Just a little late to the party, I already have my solution apart from distinguishing between tables.

Comment: No it doesn'. I just tried it and it gives the same results as earlier which is nothing.

Comment: you check it again @user3968645

Answer (score 0):

Since delegated jQuery events (such as `.live` and `.on`[with appropriate arguments]) are a performance impact, I would add the listener to an upper level element and test for target. Since there could be empty rows, set a default value of zero `$(this).val()) || 0`. Convert to a `Number`, not integer, since you need cent values. Fix the result to two digits after the dot.

```
$('#myTable').change(function (ev)
{
  if (ev.target.classList.contains('amount'))
  {
    var total = 0;

    $('.amount').each(function ()
    { total += Number($(this).val()) || 0;
    });

    $('.total_bills').html(total.toFixed(2));
  }
});
```

live test: http://jsfiddle.net/ux0rsk2q/10/

Edit: Or more in jQuery style: `if ($(ev.target).hasClass('amount'))`